# Can a Qt Application close another already launched application?

Tags: c++, qt

So here is the thing. I want to create an auto-update feature for my desktop application. What I want to do is launch a "launcher" when the application is run that will check online if there are newer versions. If there is a newer version it will download the necessary files. In either case, it will then launch the main application. So far so good

Now here comes what confuses me. When the main application has started, I want it to kill the launcher application. Problem his, how do I do this?

Hence the question. How can I kill an already launched program, programatically using Qt or plain old C++?

Comment: Qt (a library) has nothing what-so-ever to do with whether you can kill another application or not.

Comment: On Unix systems you can kill another process by sending it a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal (read "man 2 kill"). On Windows (and other operating systems) things are different.

Answer (score 2):

"Can a Qt Application close another already launched application?" - Yes. Just as much as a non-Qt application can. Qt is irrelevant in that regard. What matters is your Operating System.
On Unix systems you can send another process a SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal (which will be delivered or nor depending on various rules you should read up on). Windows (and other operating systems) also have ways of terminating processes - read their documentation. But, in any case; Qt has *nothing* to do with this.

Comment: HI! Thanks for the answer. I know this is an operating system capability. But I thougtht maybe Qt had a SO independant class that could do this somehow. One of the main draws for Qt. Just like QProcess can launch a new application (Window or Linux) or a Qthread a new thread (Windows or Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can approach the problem differently, and start the original app, let it check for an update. if an update is availabe, close itself after the updater has been started. And restart it from the updater. All that does work with QProcess!

Comment: If you do this, aren't you still left with he problem of closing the updater after the app was restarted?

Comment: No. Same as the App can close itself after launching the Updater, the Updater can close itself after launching the App again.1) App launches Updater. 2) App closes itself. 3) Updater updates everything except himself. We copy the updater and its runtimes to a temp dir, for the updater to be able to update runtimes as well. 4) Updater starts updated App. 5) Updater closes itself.